# Permission denied after Token generated using Approle Harshcorp Vault

Tags: hashicorp-vault

I'm integrating Harshicorp Vault into application. I have used AppRole auth backend. I have followed all the steps on AppRole documentation and obtained the role_id and secret_id for the role to perform login as well. After that I was able to perform a login and obtained the client_token required for connecting with the Vault engine.But when using that generated client_token as vault token I get a permission denied error.

The same behavior is there even when I follow the same flow from the example in getting started to vault api official documentation.

https://learn.hashicorp.com/vault/getting-started/apis

Answer (score 0):

As you have not mentioned which version of K/V (key-value) engine you are using, there is one thing you need to check while creating policies for your role.

Make sure that the path for which you have defined policy constraints should end with *.

For example, for providing create, read and update permissions for a path secret/data/foo/bar, following definition needs to be added to your policy file (.hcl)

```
path "secret/data/foo/bar*" {
   capabilities = ["create","read","update"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but wanted to share my issue. I had very similar symptoms, and I'm using HCP (the cloud hosted Vault from Hashicorp). The issue I ran into was not setting the namespace I was logging in to. In HCP, the namespace is "admin" (I think it's the only namespace allowed) and you need to specify it.

Setting the namespace via environment variable can be done like this:

```
export VAULT_NAMESPACE="admin"
```